# How to get the class field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have appended the style using jQuery as follow:

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .highlightStyle{ fill:red;stoke-width:2;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

My question is: how to get the `highlightStyle` field (`fill` and `stroke-width`)?

Comment: @KaranPatyal. OP wants to GET and not SET.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.css(arg)` with argument as property name to get its value:

```
var divhighlightStyle = $('<div class="highlightStyle"></div>');
var fill= divhighlightStyle.css('fill') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a function like this?

```
 changestyle = function ($fill = 'red',$stroke = 2) {
    $('.highlightStyle').css({ill:$fill,toke-width:$stroke});
    }
   changestyle('#ccc',5);
```

Comment: because i will change the fill color in some other time.. if we use u r code each and every time i need to append

Answer (score 0):

Append method is used when want to insert specified content at the end of the selected elements here you want to add class in yours HTML element so this is done by using addClass() method ex:

```
$("head").addClass(".highlightStyle");
```

you can define this class in CSS using Style Tag

```
<style>
.highlightStyle{
background:red;
}
```

Comment: in my scenarios i need to append the style in dynamically.. when i hover the window that time i can get the element color and add the class(highlightStyle)